# JavaScript: Why is the console output of these 2 seemingly-equivalent programs subtly different?

Tags: javascript

This program:

```
 var arr = [];
    arr[100] = "foo";
    console.log(arr);
```

Outputs this:

```
(101) [undefined × 100, "foo"]
```

However, this program:

```
var arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
arr[i] = (i === 100 ? "foo" : undefined);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Outputs this (there is a `"foo"` eventually, of course):

```
(101) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined…]
```

I could be nitpicking but I just want to make sure, why is the output different ? Shouldn't the 2 arrays be equivalent ?

Running in Chrome version 58.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Yeah certainly, I just didn't know the proper terminology to google the question.

Comment: in the first case the keys from 0 to 99 are not created. You can try `console.log(Object.create(arr))` in both cases to notice the difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're not equivalent.

The first one is sparse with only a single member at index `100`. The second one has 101 members, most of which are the value `undefined`.

A sparse array is one where there are fewer members than the `.length` suggests. So if you have an array where `.length` is `101` and all indices have a value, it's not sparse, but if there are "holes" where an actual index/value is missing, it's a sparse array.

To check if an array is sparse, you can compare its `.length` to the `.length` of the result of `Object.keys`.

```
var isSparse = arr.length !== Object.keys(arr).length;
```

To check if a single member is actually defined or not, use the `in` operator: `3 in arr` Or the `.hasOwnProperty()` method: `arr.hasOwnProperty(3)`

Comment: This was exactly why I asked the question, I did sort of know that they were not equivalent, but what does "sparse" mean ? Could you elaborate ? When is an array sparse ? Can anything else be sparse ?

Comment: Sparse means that there are fewer members than the `.length` suggests. So if you have an array where `.length` is `101`, if all indices have a value, it's not sparse, but if there are "holes" where an actual value is missing, it's a sparse array

Comment: So how could one distinguish between the two if you didn't know which was sparse and which wasn't ? How could you programmatically determine which array is sparse ?

Comment: You could do this to check if it's sparse or not: `arr.length === Object.keys(arr).length`. If they're equal, it's not sparse.

Comment: Great, both solutions work, incorporate your comments into your answer if you want it accepted, or I will just edit it and accept it later :)